# `bitcoind` RPC: ask if syncing headers or blocks

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, json-rpc

Is there a way to know from `bitcoind` RPC if it's syncing headers or blocks? And is there a way to know the header sync progress?

Even if not directly available, is it possible to derive header sync progress from other information through RPC?

I tried to get this information from the debug log, but the problem there is that occasionally, the last header sync log message looks like this

```
Synchronizing blockheaders, height: 1660930 (~95.02%)
```

It never logs out whether it reached 100% or not, and that's a problem for the software that I'm working on.

Answer (score 2):

The `getblockchaininfo` RPC will tell you have many blocks and headers you have. When the number of headers is larger, you're still synchronizing.

Comment: I'm not asking about whether `bitcoind` is syncing blocks or not. I'm talking about the header-first sync. I want to know the progress of that.

Comment: Oh, I misread. In that case the answer is even easier: you can't know.

Comment: Pieter, what about comparing `startingheight` from the `getpeerinfo` response with the `header` field from the `getblockchaininfo` response?

Comment: Your peers can trivially lie in that field.

Comment: Yes, but should be good enough for providing sync progress status to the end-user, no?

Comment: If an approximate answer is enough, you can just look at the timestamp of the last header. That's more accurate than relying on startingheight (which will be outdated for long lived connections).

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that there is no exact answer to this question: your node is *always* syncing headers, and is never "done". There may be a block that was just mined, but you haven't learned about, so you can never be sure you're caught up.